# Typescript String enum type 'string' is not assignable to type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocgeirgHUkAbNXJOGCdgCzYBUBPMEgDKaKMDDwACoxT8A5jgCuAOwAmAGm7AAznF1wUcAO5IARjuAwk1Wsa7A0XOPOAA3JHv4QlhuE5QVNDYOE3FrLR0uFCJDdThGVCgVOAEhUXFJADpKGjgATR9-H0Y1bRUAazgITH14YBSYLiI2YzkdAC5bWzg4AFo4AEE4MFlg9k5EmJS0kTEJepSjUfRWnliVCCaG+X9AuDMiFAqe-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)

Pretty simple, how do I avoid this compile error?

```
type ExampleClass = {
    relevantValue: EXAMPLE_STRING_ENUM;
}

enum EXAMPLE_STRING_ENUM {
    HELLO = 'hello',
}

const exampleArray: ExampleClass[] = [];

const mockData = {
    relevantValue: 'hello'
}

exampleArray.push(mockData);
```

results in

> Argument of type '{ relevantValue: string; }' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'ExampleClass'.   Types of property 'relevantValue'
> are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'EXAMPLE_STRING_ENUM'.(2345)

In my head this should work. During writing code, I can have a switch/case statement depending on what a given field is, but the mockData comes from live, so of course it is not having an enum value, but directly the string value instead.
I thought since it is a string enum, typescript should know that the values can only be of type string?
I could just fix it by making a union type like this:

```
type ExampleClass = {
    relevantValue: EXAMPLE_STRING_ENUM | string;
}
```

but this does not really solve the underlying problem, which I am still trying to fix.
Also, this 'fix' would lead to follow up errors like such:

```
exampleArray.forEach((e) => {
setFoo(e.relevantValue)
})
```

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'SetStateAction<EXAMPLE_STRING_ENUM | undefined>'.(2345)

**EDIT**: Solved it, by typing all values where the compiler cannot know whether the string provided really is matching one of the ENUM strings, so throwing the error made sense.
Updated code:

```
const [foo, setFoo] = React.useState<EXAMPLE_STRING_ENUM>();


type ExampleClass = {
    relevantValue: string;
}

enum EXAMPLE_STRING_ENUM {
    HELLO = 'hello',
}

const exampleArray: ExampleClass[] = [];

const mockData: ExampleClass = {
    relevantValue: 'hello'
}

exampleArray.forEach((e) => {
setFoo(e.relevantValue as EXAMPLE_STRING_ENUM)
})
```

Comment: You could use `relevantValue: EXAMPLE_STRING_ENUM.HELLO` (see [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAVEBW)) or use an union type instead of the enum (e.g. in the type definition: `relevantValue: 'hello' | 'goodBye'`, see [here](https://tsplay.dev/mpD46m)). Is there a reason those don't work for you?

Comment: I have written in my first post why I cannot use the first solution proposed, and I do not understand how the second one solves the problem.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that you want to use external strings. In that case, I would suggest to use a type guard, that assures it is indeed an EXAMPLE_STRING_ENUM. This would keep the type safety, even when the live data is messed up. [Here](https://tsplay.dev/wXk5kW) is an example

Comment: And if you found an answer yourself, it's usually better to post it as an answer (even if it's your own question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a guard to the mockData constant to let Typescript know that relevantValue is constrained to values in the enum:

```js
const mockData: ExampleClass = {
    relevantValue: EXAMPLE_STRING_ENUM.HELLO
}
```

If you don't do this then the following is allowed, which is why typescript errors in your example:

```js
mockData.relevantValue = 'not an enum value';
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCoASMFmgY7p7ehCTkVOle4jUMdRLYTqCc8LEZzCZmoNJODPHFZZXVtZYYkAAeRJTInDQS8po+rf40gnjbDKv8LqD2jpbYoACqAEoAMsK7sUmxkGSCc+VVQQuaTwVb1UBrDYULY7PagbgUZLJH6QbYmJAECjuMigZEMVDsJzCFLNXxtajBBCcQQ0MwAUVWDEQNUgADVHBQGNJ3KAALygABEAAkYNAMOB4GRogLFFTBPB3AExcwABT0xnM9zsyhc9wASmCKhwDQ8ZC8iElzhB7Bo3zcZmY7AYzEg-Fg0HUiS58D0Ii8AoZTJZggFSRxAvADlQAHJhAA5SASAVBFQAeW+ZF2gldWkgx1QjgUrmkeFATgtOlGWH0KAQiBhwiudokkuiIgMHBx3RYbC43CCilQLVAgc1kAAwoxBMJ+QBvRQlEpOdw6MyodnQdiQfIjgAaFQAsrQXnSAPrEHBPACScYA4qe6XGHgeANyKAC+wVR7EQe8Px7PC9rzvB8nwPUB50XUAhTpF4XlTPlQGjbBoDFaNeA-Sl4GpGg1iDdwKjIMgmB3UcWUnBhpwAbQAXUQ2i31lbCaVAC1YHiAARfEGFIjVyKnGcIIXRdl0gVdtg3LdSP3I8T3PS8b3vR9nwCGC4NTTDFDwsdCOIvAAgIdh7BVNjOO4vUXyAA)

Comment: I copied it to the playground link ([here](https://tsplay.dev/m3zkAN)) and got the error `Type '"hello"' is not assignable to type 'EXAMPLE_STRING_ENUM'`. I don't know if there is a way to use a string constant instead of directly using the enum

Comment: Oh yes, in the case of a literal object you'll have to say: `EXAMPLE_STRING_ENUM.HELLO`. Updating my answer. But as long as you type the foreign data as being `ExampleClass` objects (including the enum property) the array pushes should work anyway.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Typing the mockData does not solve cause, only the symptom.
See the last updated part with the setState function - typescript does not realize that this string enum only contains string, even though I used the string enum notation. I want typescript that all values have to be of type string.

Comment: Ah I see your edited post now, yes. the `mockData.relevantValue = 'not an enum value' is exactly why the compiler throws an error and it is right in doing so. I realized that. Thank you!

Comment: The error you display - `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<EXAMPLE_STRING_ENUM | undefined>'` - hints to me that you still have the `EXAMPLE_STRING_ENUM | string` union in the `ExampleClass` type, am I correct?. That's not useful, because any `EXAMPLE_STRING_ENUM` is already a string, so the entire type simplifies to `string`.

Comment: I did it the other way around. Removed union and kept `EXAMPLE_STRING_ENUM` for the compiler to be more strict